# trying to transfer content from a ol to ul

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, parent-child

I'm trying to move the li elements from a li list that contains 4 elements (first, second, third, fourth) to a newly created ol element. I decided to create the ol elemend and append the elements to it in a for loop, and then use replacechild to switch out the lists, but the result that I am getting is a new ol list with only two elements inside: first, third

it seems that the iterator skips one element at a time and I don't understand why?

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="update" onclick="updateList()">
<ul id="ul"><li>first</li><li>second</li><li>third</li><li>fourth</li></ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function updateList() {

    var list = document.getElementById("ul");
    var newList = document.createElement("ol");

    var nodes = list.childNodes;

    for(i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        newList.appendChild(nodes[i]);
    }
parent = list.parentNode;
parent.replaceChild(newList, list)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move element 0, element 1 becomes element 0, and so on. Just move them in a `while` loop, while they exist:

```js
function updateList() {

    var ul = document.getElementById("ul"),
        ol = document.createElement("ol");

    while (ul.childNodes.length) {
        ol.appendChild(ul.childNodes[0]);
    }

    ul.parentNode.replaceChild(ol, ul);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updateList()">
<ul id="ul"><li>first</li><li>second</li><li>third</li><li>fourth</li></ul>
```